# How to use bootstrap dropdown(ng2-bootstrap) in ag-grid-ng2

Tags: angular, ag-grid, ng2-bootstrap

This is url of github [issue](https://github.com/ceolter/ag-grid-ng2/issues/16)

Any assistance would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Why you want to use ag-grid-ng2?

Comment: I want this component to be written in angular2 . So I thought this one will be fit into my requirement

Comment: Another option is datatable from primeNG - http://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/datatable

Answer (score 0):

You use bootstrap directly no need for extra attention for tweeter bootstrap unless you are not going for hash location strategy so for that use ROUTER_PROVIDERS.